# Data type missmatch in criteria expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Is there any wrong in this SQL statement in VBA:

```
myConnection.Execute "update item_gallery set quantity = 'qtToTotal' where item =  'Desc' and gallery ='Gallery_Name'"
where 
qtToTotal = qtTo + qtFrom

 While Not myRecordSetItem.EOF

        If !item_ID = myRecordSetItem.Fields("item_ID").Value Then
            Desc = myRecordSetItem.Fields("Desc").Value
        End If

        myRecordSetItem.MoveNext

    Wend

    While Not myRecordSetGallery.EOF

        If !To = myRecordSetGallery.Fields("Gallery_ID").Value Then
            Gallery_Name = myRecordSetGallery.Fields("Gallery_Name").Value
        End If

        myRecordSetGallery.MoveNext

    Wend
```

it always give me the message :

> "data type missmatch in criteria expression"

Comment: 1) How does this code compile? `where qtToTotal = qtTo + qtFrom` is outside of the string literal. 2) You aren't showing the assignment to `myRecordsetItem`. If your problem is with the line beginning `myConnection.Execute ...` then all the rest of the code is irrelevant to your question. 3) Presumably, `quantity` is a numeric field, and you are trying to set it's value to the string `"qtToTotal"`, not the value in the field named `qtToTotal`.

Comment: I removed the qute from qtToTotal beacause it is integer, but I got another error message : "No value give for one  or  more parameter"

Comment: 1) This should go without saying, but please edit and repost your corrected code. 2) Please correct the first two points of my previous comment. I suggest you read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) carefully. 3) Is `qtToTotal` a field in the underlying table/query `item_gallery`?

Comment: Please add your original code that gives you `data type missmatch in criteria expression` error message ;).

Comment: @BurhanBarhoush from your code what we understand is that. qtToTotal is an variable and its value is assigning to the quantity field through the query..but where is the code which assigining the parameter..

Comment: @BurhanBarhoush `myConnection.Execute "update item_gallery set quantity =" & qtToTotal & " where item =  'Desc' and gallery ='Gallery_Name'"` i think this is what you needed

Comment: the problem is still exists

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
myConnection.Execute "update item_gallery set quantity = 'qtToTotal' where item =  'Desc' and gallery ='Gallery_Name'"
where 
qtToTotal = qtTo + qtFrom
```

Looks like it should read more like this (but I'm not 100% as I have some questions to ask):

```
myConnection.Execute "UPDATE item_gallery" _
                   & " SET quantity = qtToTotal" _
                   & " WHERE item = Desc" _
                   & " AND gallery = Gallery_Name" _
                   & " AND qtToTotal = (qtTo + qtFrom)"
```

My guess is you're getting this error because you've surrounded what look like field names in single quotes (`'`), which is what you do when you're telling SQL that you're wanting a piece of text rather than one of the fields in your database.

Examples of when to use single quotes:

> ...when you want to refer to just a piece of text in a field formatted as text:
>
> `"SELECT * FROM tblNames WHERE FirstName = 'John'"`.
>
> ...when you want to refer to text that's currently in a field on an open form that is formatted as text:
>
> `"SELECT * FROM tblNames WHERE FirstName = '" & Me.txtFirstName & "'"`.

But in your case it looks like you want a field from the underlying tables, so you don't need any single quotes around the field name.

Your `quantity` field sounds like it could well be a numeric field and you've essentially asked it to try and put the piece of text "qtToTotal" in the `quantity` field, which it won't be able to do if that field is only setup to accept numbers.

A few questions though as I suspect there might be more problems here (and I'll update this based on your answers):

1. Are all these fields...

   - quantity
   - qtToTotal
   - item
   - Desc
   - gallery
   - qtToTotal
   - qtTo
   - qtFrom

...located in the table **item_gallery**?

If they're not then you need to create `JOIN`(s) in your SQL statement between the **item_gallery** table and whatever table(s) the other fields come from using a field that matches/relates the records from both tables.

2. What is the data type for each of these fields?

Where you've used an `=` between 2 fields, are both those fields the same data type? If not it will cause a mismatch.

**Also**: I'd advise against using "Desc" as a field name as `DESC` is a word reserved for "descending order" in an `ORDER BY` clause in SQL.